# Rails helper method method not works in PDF if sending as an attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf

Hi i have create a PDF conversion in my rails application using Prawn and it working fine.
Now i am sending that PDf in an email attachment. Now problem is that i can send PDF attachment if i do not use any helper method, but when i use my format_currency method in PDf file it gives error on instance_eval method. here is my code sample:
format currency code:

```
module ApplicationHelper

def format_currency(amt)
    unit = 'INR'
    country = current_company.country
    if !country.blank? && !country.currency_unicode.blank?
      unit = country.currency_unicode.to_s
    elsif !country.blank? 
      unit = country.currency_code.to_s
    end
    number_to_currency(amt, :unit => unit+" ", :precision=> 2)   
  end 
end
```

My controller code :

```
pdf.instance_eval do
      @company = current_company
      @invoice = invoice
      @invoice_line_items = invoice_line_items
      @receipt_vouchers = receipt_vouchers
      eval(template) #this evaluates the template with your variables
    end
```

the error message i got :

```
undefined method `format_currency' for #<Prawn::Document:0x7f89601c2b68>
```

with this code i can send attachment successfuly if i don't use helper method but i need to use that method.

Comment: why are you calling instance-eval on your prawn document. that looks hackish to me! the code that you are executing is evaluated within the context of the prawn doc. unless you mixin your apphelper into the document, you do not have access to those method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue in a different manner, i have created a new currency_code method in my company model and called that in my format_currency helper method and it is working for me fine:
Here is what i have done :

```
def currency_code
  unit = 'INR'
  if !country.blank? && !country.currency_unicode.blank?
      unit = country.currency_unicode.to_s
  elsif !country.blank? 
      unit = country.currency_code.to_s
  end
   unit
end
```

and used it in my format_currency helper :

```
def format_currency(amt)
    unit = current_company.currency_code
    number_to_currency(amt, :unit => unit+" ", :precision=> 2)   
  end
```

and in my controller i have added a variable for currency and used it in my pdf file:

```
 pdf.instance_eval do
      @company = current_company
      @invoice = invoice
      @invoice_line_items = invoice_line_items
      @receipt_vouchers = receipt_vouchers
      @currency = current_company.currency_code # new added variable for currency
      eval(template) #this evaluates the template with your variables
    end
```